# Implicit private function import?

Tags: go

How is `main.go` able to use `buildIndexMapping`?

The function is not uppercased so how is it publicly accessible within the package and that too without an explicit import of `mapping.go`?

**main.go**: https://github.com/blevesearch/beer-search/blob/721fab2198a52d919133df08058fde8043bab365/main.go#L55

**mapping.go**: https://github.com/blevesearch/beer-search/blob/721fab2198a52d919133df08058fde8043bab365/mapping.go#L19

Comment: I don't see why this question is downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are in the same package. In Go you import packages, not files, thus the private function is available.

Comment: So, for fork and develop purposes, I'd have to look through all files in the package to hunt for where functions are written via grep?

Comment: @paulkon how is this different than any other language that can compile from multiple files?  You can use whatever tooling your comfortable with. The standard `godoc` is very useful for this.

Comment: @paulkon Yes. All the files of a package form that package. Lower-case symbols have package-scope, not file-scope.

Comment: @paulkon I recommend using a good editor, sublime text + gosublime or atom with goplus or even vim.